# How to set img tag vertical center : html + css

Tags: html, css, image

I'm coding it

```
<div>
 <a href="http://example1.com">
   <img src="example1.gif" />
 </a>
</div>
<div>
 <a href="http://example2.com">
   <img src="example2.gif" />
 </a>
</div>

a {
  text-align:center;
  height :80px;
  display:block;
}
```

The centering of the horizontal direction do well.
but  vertical is not.
How to do it?
By the way, the height of example2.gif is different from example1.gif

Answer (score 1):

You will want to set `vertical-align: middle;` on your `img` elements.