# How can i design a div shown in image using 4corner images,4 line images,and a content div

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I want to design a div.i have 4corners images,4line image.i only want a way using these images, as it will work in ie too.i know 'div inside a div trick' for having 4corners at position but how to place those line images correctly??keep in mind i have all heights in percentages.i want a div so that i can place data..show clearly your data div

cant put image as new user...so generating image wid text :(

```
 -----------------------------------------
|   suppose corners are there.            |
|   i cant make these lines(left,right)   |
|<--i have image of these line also. ---->|                                         
|                                         |
|                                         |
|                                         |
|                                         |
 -----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

> http://ulmanen.fi/stuff/box.php

That was an answer to a similar question:

> [Can div really override table for everything on layouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009405/can-div-really-override-table-for-everything-on-layouts)

Comment: @Aakash Sahai, don't forget to mark this answer as accepted if it was helpful and solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use CSS3, you can use the new property for border image. Just thought to mention it since it's a different approach although not compatible with older browsers.

You can see how to use it in the W3C website:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-border-20021107/#the-border-image-uri